# Lotus Notes/Domino Designer 8 - Disable shared action refresh

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am working in Lotus Notes 8 using the Domino Designer to update a shared action under:

```
Shared Code >> Actions
```

Every night when the database refreshes my changes are being wiped out.  Other files have a do not refresh option in them but, the actions do not.  Does anyone know how I can update the file to not be over-written (without updating the database file name to a non-existing one and leaving the nightly refresh on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the design properties of the entire list of Shared Actions and turn off design refresh/replace, but it doesn't appear you can control this on an individual action

I clicked Shared Code > Actions > and then right-clicked on "Shared Actions" in the designer, and clicked Design Properties.  There I saw the "Do not allow design refresh/replace to modify"

Comment: You can't do it on an individual shared action because of the way shared actions are implemented. They rely on a 'share-id' rather than a design element Note ID, or name, or spot in the list. It makes using them in a templated environment tricky. It MAY cause problems down the road (well, we're already 3 years down the road here) with the forms and views pointing at a share-id that is in use in the template that is not the same action as in the database.